# hadoop/yarn/spark executor memory increase

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

when I execute a spark-submit command with  **--master  yarn-cluster   --num-executors 7 --driver-memory 10g --executor-memory 16g --executor-cores 5**, I get the below error, I am not sure where to change the heap size, I suspect Yarn config files somewhere, Please advice

**error**

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx10g
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.**
```

Comment: What Java installation do you have on your cluster? Are you using a 32-bit JVM anywhere?

Comment: > java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_161"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b14, mixed mode), Also when I removed the  --driver-memory 10g, the spark job starts.

Comment: The error message and your 10g heap size point to the fact that you're running **the driver** on a 32-bit jvm. And because this is submitted in **cluster-mode**, the version of Java needs to be checked on your cluster nodes (where yarn will ultimately execute the driver), not where spark-submit was run. So you need to check the installation on all yarn nodes and make sure that if multiple versions of java are installed, the JAVA_HOME variable is not being set through any config file or environment variable to an unintended installation directory.

Comment: Thanks , I am running everything on the same box , The only jdk I have is 64bit and JAVA_HOME is pointing to that.

Comment: If it's all on the same box, how are you getting 7 executors with 16g of memory and 5 cores? That's over 100G of RAM and 45 CPU cores... You seem to have a cluster, so we're asking you to check all the YARN nodes

Comment: you are right, I had an 586 rpm installed